# Other programming languages in colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is it possible that Google also includes other languages in colab apart from Python? The truth is that I would be interested if they include Ruby

Excuse me for my English, I know it's bad.

Comment: Hi. Please use the platform for asking technical questions, this seems more dependent on specific company product's roadmap. Alternatively, you can use websites like replit.com/languages/ruby